Clarification on Theorem 6 from Uniswap V1 Formalized Model: e_0 < e_2 and t_0 < t_2


References:

a link to the parent site
Formalized Model Document


Yes, when everything is 0 there is equality

From my perspective, what you are missing based on your question is context on data types.
For instance, uniswap exchange contract stores amounts in uint256: https://github.com/Uniswap/v1-contracts/blob/master/contracts/uniswap_exchange.vy.
uint is treated arithmetically as an unsigned value, which can never be negative.
Can solidity have negative numbers?
So, the deltas and every other variable is always non-negative in the context of the provided theorems.

please do not look at the integers

Sorry, but I don't see how this is related to my question

You have copy pasted theorem from the research paper, please update your answer to reflect your thinking process. I do not have the time to reconstruct the full theorem. I found a seeming mistake in your logic, if it is not the case, it might help somebody else.
